# How to make C++ class have specific size in memory

Tags: c++, io, memcpy

I am given a C++ framework (that I can't change) for IO operations that works like this:

- It has `block_size` which is the size of block that is read or written
- Each read/write operation gets this operation struct:

> ```
> struct Operation {
>    size_t block;  // index of external memory block
>    void * data;   // here the data will be written or read from
> }
> ```

The the actual read or write looks like this:

> ```
> Operation o; 
> o.block = 42; // index of block i want to read from
> o.data = // where i want the data to end up
> io.read(o);
> ```

The problem is that the read/write is implemented with `memcpy` and it always moves block of `block_size` bytes. However when I want to save and load my class `X` to this external memory I have a problem, because probably `sizeof(X) != block_size`.

So when I would do this:

> ```
> X x;
> Operation o; 
> o.block = 42; // index of block i want to read from
> o.data = &x;
> io.read(o);
>
> io.write(o);
> ```

If `sizeof(X) < block_size` I have a problem during the read, because more bytes than I want will be read, possibly corrupting the stack.
If `sizeof(X) > block_size` I have a problem during write, because not every byte of `X` will be written so I have an incomplete backup of it.

I want to use each block for one instance of `X` and I can make sure that `sizeof(X) < block_size`. Is there some way how to add some padding bytes to `X`, so it has exactly `block_size` bytes?

Comment: Is `block_size` a constant known at compile time?

Comment: An object allocator which adds padding internally might help.

Comment: @FabioTurati yes the block_size is compile time constant.

Comment: Note that reading/writng pointer values is often a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk I know, but this is what I have been given. I don't have the choice to change the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X x;
Operation o; 
o.block = 42; // index of block i want to read from
o.data = &x;
io.read(o);
```

Well, you can't do that, as you yourself said. You **must** point to a `block_size` block, then copy into the relevant class:

```
BYTE buffer[block_size];
X x;
Operation o; 
o.block = 42; // index of block i want to write to
o.data = buffer;
io.read(o);
memcpy(&x, buffer, sizeof(X));
```

Ditto for writes (you can't simply write whatever happens to be after the end of X because you may fall off the cliff into an unmapped page):

```
BYTE buffer[block_size];
X x;
Operation o; 
o.block = 42; // index of block i want to read from
o.data = buffer;
memcpy(buffer, &x, sizeof(X));
io.write(o);
```

I won't comment on the sanity of the interface itself. And `static_assert(sizeof(X) <= block_size)`. And the type `X` must be memcopy safe.

There are more tricks in the book, like make the `sizeof(X)` always match `block_size` (via padding) or use allocation tricks (always allocate X in block_size regions, never use on stack). But copy before write/after read is the simplest, least tricky.